How can put a Facebook Open Graph into Razor component instead of APP.Razor in ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor
I want to put below open graph according to razor pages - how we can do that?
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:description"">
<meta property="og:image" content="">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600">

I tested it, but when you put on headoutlead as below code in the razor page, it is not working on Facebook because it is not first rendering:
<HeadContent>
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <meta property="og:title" content="">
    <meta property="og:description"">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="600">
</HeadContent>

